# Vertically flip ASCII art with Python

Tags: python, arrays

for another code that I am working on, I need to vertically flip an ASCII image:
I want to make this:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
    ***
    ***
```

into this:

```
    ***
    ***
   *****
    ***
     *
```

All I have right now is to read input on multiple lines into an array, but how do I make it so that it prints the first array last and the bottom array first.

```
text = ""
stopword = ""
while True:
    line = input()
    if line.strip() == stopword:
        break
```

Comment: Push each line onto a stack, and then pop them one by one to produce the output.

Comment: Would this work for any input? I am trying to make it so that any 'picture' inputted will be able to be reversed. Sorry, I am only a beginner at this so my apologies if this is an easy question.

Comment: Yes, it would work for any input.  It works because a stack is first-in, first out.

Comment: Depending on what your idea of "flip" is, you might need to swap some characters as well (e.g, `b` for `p`, ``\`` for `/`…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add each line to a list of lines (`list.append`) and then invert that list (`list[::-1]`) before printing:

```
lines = []
stopword = ""
while True:
    line = input()
    if line.strip() == stopword:
        break
    lines.append(line) # Add to the list of lines
for line in lines[::-1]: # [::-1] inverts the list
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a reasonable use-case for a `deque` - you can use `.extendleft` with any iterable.

```
from collections import deque

stop_word = '' # an empty line causes a stop
lines_until_stop = iter(input, stopword)
d = deque()
d.extendleft(lines_until_stop)
print(*d, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify everything by just reversing all the lines using [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed).

```
>>> art = '''
...      *
...     ***
...    *****
...     ***
...     ***
... '''
>>> print('\n'.join(reversed(art.splitlines())))
    ***
    ***
   *****
    ***
     *
```

I am feeling generous today, so for your complete example:

```
text = ""
stopword = "END"
lines = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line.strip() == stopword:
        break
    lines.append(line)

print('\n'.join(reversed(lines)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in lines[::-1]:
    print item
```